# Can not load images with jQuery script with load function

Tags: jquery, html, loading

I'm using a jQuery script to load a nav.html and a footer.html. My problem is when I'm testing my website in Wamp, it's fine. When I load it into my real web server, it won't load my logo. I couldn't figure out why and I couldn't find anything.

Here is my nav.html

```
<meta content="text/html;charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type">
<meta content="utf-8" http-equiv="encoding">
<html>
 <head>
  <title></title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" async>
 </head>
 <body border="1" style="hight:60, border-bottom: 5px solid cyan; vertical-align: middle;">
  <br>
  <img src="attf.png" width="256px">
  <a id="button" href="index.html">Home</a>
  <a id="button" href="gameserv.html">Game Servers</a>
  <a id="button" href="comsserv.html">Communication Servers</a>
  <br>
  <br>
 </body>
</html>
```

and here is how I'm loading nav.html into my web pages.

```
<head>
 <title></title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" async>
 <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
 <script>
  $(function(){
   $("#nav").load("nav.html");
   $("#footer").load("footer.html");
  });
 </script>
</head>
<body border="1">
 <div id="nav"></div>
 <div id="footer"></div>
</body>
```

If it helps you can find my website at http://attf.us/.

Comment: Did you upload http://attf.us/afft.png - that's a 404 at the moment?

Comment: in general, these kind of errors are solved opening the **developer tools**. In Chrome Menu, select More Tools > Developer Tools. In Safari and Firefox is something similar. Those tools have a console that prints out the errors found in your page. Probably you are getting 404's (file not found) because of an incorrect path or a forgotten upload.

Comment: With Firefox I use FireBug and just have to do F12 to open it. https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/firebug/

Comment: Yeah it is there, it's weird because it can't load it for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

You are loading a full HTML page in a `<div>`.

The nav.html should not include the `<html>`, `<head>`, and `<body>` tags. That is not correct within a `<div>` tag.

Change it to something like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" async>
<div border="1" style="hight:60, border-bottom: 5px solid cyan; vertical-align: middle;">
 <br>
 <img src="attf.png" width="256px">
 <a id="button" href="index.html">Home</a>
 <a id="button" href="gameserv.html">Game Servers</a>
 <a id="button" href="comsserv.html">Communication Servers</a>
 <br>
 <br>
</div>
```

For the stylesheet, you may want to look into something different to place the `<link>` tag in the `<head>` but it probably works inline. Another way is to use the `<style>` tag for your CSS, but that makes it 100% inline which may not be what you want.

Comment: Okay, I'll make some corrections and let you know how it works. Also thank you for editing my mistakes. :)

Comment: I made the corrections and only left everything that was inside the body tag and tested it in my Wamp environment and everything looks the same. I moved the new files over to the web server and I'm still having the same problems. :/

Comment: To make sure the cache is not a problem, you may want to look at the source (right click, *View Page Source* in Firefox)

Comment: Yeah for now I can avoid using any CSS styles in the nav. The source at http://attf.us/nav.html shows the img tag, it just doesn't want to load.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks too Alexis for information to a better building habit. Also geedubbs and rupps for pointing out it could of been a bad path or other similar problem.

I figured out my web server is case sensitive.

Thanks y'all, this had me running in circles for about an hour.